# RegEx: Match until an nth word

Tags: string, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

So I have the following cases:

```
> **Started by user** by Bla bla bla 
> **Started by a upstream** project by bla bla
> **Start by a commit** by more needless information
```

I need to get basically only get the strings only until the build cause
For example "Start by user", but I don't if it will be user, upstream project or a commit.
So I think I require a regex in this situation, but I'm sure on how to achieve that.

```
  CAUSE = "${currentBuild.getBuildCauses()[0].shortDescription}"
```

Only information I'm sure about that it will produce is "
Started by a ****(I need the reason here - (user, upstream project, commit) | everything else should be ommited

End result expected:

```
Started by a user 
Started by an upstream project 
Started by a commit
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your intention and use case really is you can get along like this:

```
CAUSE = currentBuild.getBuildCauses()[0].shortDescription
CAUSE.replaceAll("Started by a?", "").split(" ")[0]
```

But I personally would check for the Cause.class, rather than using regex. This way you can also easily get the user name or upstream job or whatever the cause brings you (https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Cause.html), like Cause.UserCause or Cause.UpstreamCause.

Comment: The thing is I don't need the name, I just need the cause. "Started by a user, started by an upstream job". Don't care for anything after

Comment: @WhoAmI Then still both my solutions will work. With my first proposal you will get a string which is either "user", "upstream" or "commit". And with this you can switch/case or if/else through your code. Or 2nd option, use the class of the Cause rather than the string to do the same thing as described in lot more details in ycr's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this.

```
script{
        def cause = currentBuild.getBuildCauses()[0]._class
        def message = ""
        if(cause.equals('hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause')) {
            message = "Started by a user"
        } else if(cause.equals('hudson.model.Cause$UpstreamCause')) {
            message = "Started by an upstream project "
        }
    println message
}
```